# Error in selecting random item from Dictionary in python

Tags: python, random, dictionary

I wan't to create a program that select 2 random items from two different dictionaries. Now I wan't to check if the sum of those items is equal to the value provided by the User. And i wan't to perform this action until i find 2 random items from different dictionaries that add up to the number entered by the User.

**Here is what i tried to do:**

```
import random
credit=int(raw_input("Please enter your amount: "))
food=dict([(10, 'Lays'), (10,'Pepsi'), (10,'Burger')])
toys=dict([(10, 'Car'), (10,'Train'), (10,'Chess')])
ranf=random.choice(food.keys())
rant=random.choice(toys.keys())
while int(ranf)+int(rant)!=credit:
    ranf=random.choice(food.keys())
    rant=random.choice(toys.keys())
print(ranf)
print(food[ranf])
print(rant)
print(food[rant])
```

When i try to run this code it fails to print those two random items. I'm not getting any error message. Please run this code and help me out.

Thank You

Comment: Why not just create the dictionary like `food = {10: 'Burger'}`/etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within the fact, that you create your dictionaries with duplicate keys - effectively, your `food` dictionary contains only `(10,'Burger')` and your toys dictionary has only `(10,'Chess')` item (they both contain only most recently added item, which replaced all the previous ones). The simplest and quickest fix would be to abandon the usage of a dictionary:

```
import random
credit=20
food=[(10, 'Lays'), (10,'Pepsi'), (10,'Burger')]
toys=[(10, 'Car'), (10,'Train'), (10,'Chess')]
ranf=random.choice(food)
rant=random.choice(toys)
while int(ranf[0])+int(rant[0])!=credit:
    ranf=random.choice(food)
    rant=random.choice(toys)

print(ranf)
print(rant)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton bro! i loved your explanation. Hats off to you (Y)

Answer (score 1):

food.keys() only returns unique keys. So, essentially the only list of keys returned by the food.keys()  function is [10].
ex if you make a dictionary like food = dict([(10, 'Lays'), (15,'Pepsi'), (15,'Burger')])
then the list returned by food.keys() will be [10,15] and not [10,15,15] which is what you expect. So, in your code, if ranf = 10, then interpreter takes up the latest value assigned to that key.

Therefore, the random.choice() you are using goes in vain.
 Also, there is a silly mistake in your code, you wrote print(food[rant]) instead of writing    print(toys[rant]).

It would be better if you don't use a list, otherwise, make the keys different.